# JavaScript IF statement and While loop not working properly

Tags: javascript, if-statement, while-loop, password-generator

Okay now I have been able to solve the Length problem by adding the length property to the while loop. However, when i generate the noSpecialCharacter(), it gives me NaN in front of the generated password.

this is the function:

```
const noSpecialCharacters = () => {
    let password;
    for (let i = 0; i < askUser; i++) {
        let result3 = characterSet[randomCharacter()];
        password += result3;
    }
    return password;
}

    let askUser;
// create a function for prompts
const prompts = () => {
    const minLength = 8;
    const maxLength = 128;
    askUser = null
    while (askUser === null || askUser.length < minLength || askUser.length > maxLength) {
        // ask the user again
        askUser = prompt('Enter a password character length. Character length must be at least 8 and between 128.');
        let confirmSpecialCharacter;
        // if password is between length range
        if (askUser >= minLength && askUser <= maxLength) {
            // ask for special characters
            confirmSpecialCharacter = confirm('Would you like for your password to include special characters?');
            // if yes, call combine random
            let pass = confirmSpecialCharacter === true ? combineRandom() : noSpecialCharacters();

            alert(pass);
        }

    }

    return askUser;

}

prompts();
```

Comment: why so complicated? why to use loop?

Comment: because i want the application to reprompt the user if the password length is not in range. I tried using an if statement but after one reprompt is stopped reprompting.

Comment: confirm() returns a boolean, if (confirmSpecialCharacter === true)

Answer (score 2):

When you check the length, use askUser.length
But with this logic, when the user input is correct on the first time, nothing in the wile loop will run.

A better approach is to initialize askUser = null
and set the condition in while to:

```
while (askUser === null || askUser.length < minLength ||  askUser.length > maxLength)
```

To check first if the askUser is null

```js
let askUser;
    // create a function for prompts
    const prompts = () => {
        const minLength = 8;
        const maxLength = 128;
        askUser = null
        while (askUser === null || askUser.length < minLength ||    askUser.length > maxLength) {
            // ask the user again
            askUser = prompt('Enter a password character length. Character length must be at least 8 and between 128.');
            let confirmSpecialCharacter;
            // if password is between length range
            if (askUser.length >= minLength && askUser.length <= maxLength) {
                // ask for special characters
                confirmSpecialCharacter = confirm('Would you like for your password to include special characters?');
                // if yes, call combine random
                if (confirmSpecialCharacter === 'yes') {
                    let pass = combineRandom();
                    alert(pass);
                } else {
                    let pass = noSpecialCharacters();
                    alert(pass);
                }
    
            }
    
    
        }
    
        return askUser;
    
    }
    prompts()
```

Comment: Beat me to it :)

Comment: Okay so i added the length property to the while loop not the if statement and it worked. However, my else statement for noSpecialChracters() is not working properly. It generates passwords with special characters but not one without special characters. Is there something wrong with my logic that I am not seeing?

Comment: confirm() returns a boolean, if (confirmSpecialCharacter === true)

Answer (score 1):

Since people solved your question by adding `.length` to the `askUser`, I'm here to suggest you to reconstruct the code from `while` loop to [recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) by keep calling the function itself until it passed the validation. (code untested)

with this method you can prevent the nested condition by `return` [early](https://medium.com/swlh/return-early-pattern-3d18a41bba8).

```
// create a function for prompts
const prompts = () => {
    const minLength = 8;
    const maxLength = 128;

    // ask the user
    let askUser = prompt('Enter a password character length. Character length must be at least 8 and between 128.');

    // keep asking the function itself until it passed the validation
    if (askUser.length <= minLength || askUser.length >= maxLength || askUser === null) {
        return prompts()
    }

    // ask for special characters
    let confirmSpecialCharacter = confirm('Would you like for your password to include special characters?');
    let pass;

    // if yes, call combine random
    if (confirmSpecialCharacter) {
        pass = combineRandom();
    } else {
        pass = noSpecialCharacters();
    }

    alert(pass);
    return askUser;
}
```

With ternary condition you can get much more shorter code.

```
// if yes, call combine random
let pass = confirmSpecialCharacter ? combineRandom() : noSpecialCharacters();
```

Comment: It keeps prompting me even when the password length is in range

Comment: Hmmm, I tested the `prompt` part in Chrome console and it's working normally.

Answer (score 0):

In your while condition, you are not actually checking for `askUser` length. Change it to this line: `while (askUser.length < minLength || askUser === null || askUser.length > maxLength) { /...` And it will work.